# Count in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, count

This my query:

```
Select articles.id,articles.userid,articles.article,count(articles_likes.id), count(article_dislikes.id) 
from articles
Left join article_likes 
on article_likes.id=articles.id 
Left join article_dislikes 
on article_dislikes.id=articles.id 
group by articles.id ;
```

I want to count the number of rows in article_likes table and article_dislikes table im getting the value correct upto 2 rows..when there is a third and so on entries..I'm getting wrong counting of rows...
I don't know where the problem is ..I think I may be getting wrong values because I'm using the same table for two times...please help me

I have three tables

1)articles contains id,userid and article
2)Articles_likes table contains-like_id ,user_id and article_id
3)Articles_dislikes table contains dislike_id ,user_id and article_id

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate separately in each of the tables `articles_likes` and `articles_dislikes` and then join `articles` to the results:

```
select a.id, a.userid, a.article,
  coalesce(l.likes, 0) likes,  
  coalesce(d.dislikes, 0) dislikes
from articles a
left join (
  select article_id, count(*) likes, 
  from articles_likes
  group by article_id
) l on l.article_id = a.id
left join (
  select article_id, count(*) dislikes, 
  from articles_dislikes
  group by article_id
) d on d.article_id = a.id
```

Also the correct join of `articles_likes` and `articles_dislikes` to `articles` is by the column `article_id` to the `id` of `articles`.